# Is there a universal algorithm that can solve any Rubik's Cube?

Tags: rubiks-cube

The only reason I ask this is because solving a Rubik's Cube can be frustrating and hard, and for someone who just wants to be able to solve one it would be nice if there was a universal algorithm.

Comment: There are a set of subroutines you can execute at appropriate times to solve any cube in a short amount of effort. Provided the cube is solvable at all, that is.

Comment: Yes there is a single algorithm to solve the 3x3x3 Cube, it's called the [Devil's algorithm](http://anttila.ca/michael/devilsalgorithm/) and it's between 34,326,986,725,785,600 and 43,251,683,287,486,463,996 moves long. Even if you'd have the same turning speed as the current WR holders, you'd still take as long as the universe exists in order to execute the algorithm. Good luck with that.. ;)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the linked question, as this question does not ask for a single sequence of moves, but a single algorithm.